# NLog writing custom parameters to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, nlog

I'm trying to use NLog (ver 4) to save some data to a SQL Server table. I have a procedure with parameters that don't include any of the normal NLog params.

My `nlog.config` looks like this:

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
      name="database"
      dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionStringName="nlogConnection"
      commandText="EXEC dbo.usp_LogParserMessage @Message, @Parser, @Org, @LabOrg, @ChartNum, @AccessionId, @Status, @TransId">

  <parameter name="@Message" layout="${Message}"/>
  <parameter name="@Parser" layout="${event-properties:item=parser}"/>
  <parameter name="@Org" layout="${event-properties:item=org}"/>
  <parameter name="@LabOrg" layout="${event-properties:item=laborg}"/>
  <parameter name="@ChartNum" layout="${event-properties:item=chartnum}"/>
  <parameter name="@AccessionId" layout="${event-properties:item=accessionid}"/>
  <parameter name="@Status" layout="${event-properties:item=status}"/>
  <parameter name="@TransId" layout="${event-properties:item=transid}"/>      
</target>
```

I tried creating a custom class to populate the parameters.

```
public LogHelper(string name)
{
    _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("database");
}

public void WriteMessage(string parser, string message, string org, string laborg, string chartNum, string accessionId, string status, string transid)
{
        ///
        /// create log event from the passed message
        /// 
        LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Trace, "", message);

        //
        // set event-specific context parameter
        // this context parameter can be retrieved using ${event-context:EventID}
        //
        logEvent.Properties["parser"] = parser;
        logEvent.Properties["org"] = org;
        logEvent.Properties["laborg"] = laborg;
        logEvent.Properties["chartnum"] = chartNum;
        logEvent.Properties["accessionid"] = accessionId;
        logEvent.Properties["status"] = status;
        logEvent.Properties["transid"] = transid;

        // 
        // Call the Log() method. It is important to pass typeof(MyLogger) as the
        // first parameter. If you don't, ${callsite} and other callstack-related 
        // layout renderers will not work properly.
        //
        try
        {
            _logger.Log(logEvent);
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            string error = er.ToString();
        }
}
```

It doesn't throw an  error but also doesn't write to the database.

I'd appreciate any advice or another way to do this.

Thanks
Rut

Comment: Check the troubleshooting guide and the internal log: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting